# Basic ASP Search SQL Server with a datagrid

Tags: c#, asp.net

im trying to follow a basic asp.net videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9e0kwADEoEg to create a web page that has a textbox, button and gridview.

For some reason the gridview will never show with populated data :/ I think its because of the .fill but really not sure. I can see the query when running a trace on sql server. just no output on the webpage!? Can anyone assist?

```
ausing System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    SqlConnection vid = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=exam;Integrated Security=True");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = "select F1,F2,F3,F4 from [dbo].[CandDbase] Where F4 = '@search'";
        SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand(str,vid);
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;

        vid.Open();
        xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = xp;

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "Name");
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        vid.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you expecting result as scalar variable or datatable? if datatable, then shouldnt it be xp.ExecuteReader() instead?

Comment: Hi, changing it to xp.ExecuteQuery() errors saying no definition for SqlCommand called that.. 

and it works as shown in the vid, link to show all code just before he runs its it successfully : https://youtu.be/9e0kwADEoEg?t=10m28s

Comment: xp.ExecuteReader();

Comment: Updating to executereader it now errors when i press the button instead of doing nothing! which feels like progress :) error: 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

Source Error: 


Line 30: 
Line 31:         DataSet ds = new DataSet();
Line 32:         da.Fill(ds, "Name");
Line 33:         GridView1.DataSource = ds;
Line 34:         GridView1.DataBind();

Comment: try below code, just plugin the parameter piece in the sql adapter object. Remove the ExecuteReader piece.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the single quotes in the query:

```
string str = "select F1,F2,F3,F4 from [dbo].[CandDbase] Where F4 = @search";
```

The quotes tell Sql Server to treat `@search` as a string literal instead of an sql variable name.

Additionally, get rid of the `ExecuteNonQuery()` code. That function is for INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements.

Another issue is the SqlConnection object. Don't try to re-use the SqlConnection object in your page. .Net uses a feature called connection pooling to cache the underlying connection object, and trying to re-use the same .Net SqlConnection object instance conflicts with that. Just keep the connection string handy and create a new SqlConnection instance. Really.

There's more, too. The code below makes a number of other improvements: `using` so things are cleaned up in case of an exception, `Fill()` will open and close the connection for you, binding to a specific table, etc...

```
private const string cnString = "Server=localhost;Database=exam;Integrated Security=True";

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sql = "select F1,F2,F3,F4 from [dbo].[CandDbase] Where F4 = @search";
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cnString))
    using (SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(xp))
    {
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
        da.Fill(ds, "Name");
    }

    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Name"];
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks! updating the tsql fixed the issue! bit embarrassing!  I also tried replacing the code with yours and that also worked! so thanks x2!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>        // Open connection
>         using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(vid))
>         {
>             c.Open();
>             // 2
>             // Create new DataAdapter
>             using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(
>                 "SELECT * FROM EmployeeIDs", c))
>             {
>                 // 3
>                 // Use DataAdapter to fill DataTable
>                 DataTable t = new DataTable();
>                 a.Fill(t);
>
>                 // 4
>                 // Render data onto the screen
>                 dataGridView1.DataSource = t; // <-- From your designer
>             }
>         }
> ```